# How to find and show number of similar words in two different column within same table(MySql,PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name relation_country where there are three column 
id, country_a and country_b
and data goes like follwing...

```
id   country_a   country_b
1    USA         France
2    Australia   USA
3    France      Australia
4    India       Rassia
5    Rassia      USA
6    France      Rassia
7    USA         India
```

Here I see USA and Rassia has their won relation. Now I want to know how many of them has similar country(with).

```
say, Rassia has France & India
and USA has also France and India.
```

I can make query that shows that, USA has(France, Australia,India)
and Rassia has(France and India)
But I can't show that, these two country has similar relation with(India and France).

Please help.

Comment: can you please post your code to edit it ?

Comment: Is Rassia a country ?

Comment: Sorry, It will be Russia.( yes it is a country, I mean)

Comment: @Abkarino, Bro, I posted a query. please see it.

Comment: You should edit your post and add the code not post as answer.
Anyway I will be looking into it.

Comment: @Abkarino, I am new to this site, don't know well how to re-post, Please, I will be expart on how to post well, until take it easy, bro..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long I had to put the data locally and test it.

Here is the code you need:

```
 (SELECT DISTINCT `country_a` FROM `relation_country` WHERE(`country_b` ='USA' AND (`country_a` IN (SELECT `country_a` FROM `relation_country` WHERE `country_b`= 'Russia') OR `country_a` IN (SELECT `country_b`  FROM `relation_country` WHERE `country_a`='Russia')))) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT `country_b` FROM `relation_country` WHERE(`country_a` ='USA' AND (`country_b` IN (SELECT `country_a` FROM `relation_country` WHERE `country_b`= 'Russia') OR `country_b` IN (SELECT `country_b`  FROM `relation_country` WHERE `country_a`='Russia'))))
```

In a formatted form:

```
 (
 SELECT DISTINCT `country_a`
 FROM `relation_country`
 WHERE (
    `country_b` = 'USA'
    AND (
      `country_a`
      IN (

        SELECT `country_a`
        FROM `relation_country`
        WHERE `country_b` = 'Russia'
      )
      OR `country_a`
      IN (

        SELECT `country_b`
        FROM `relation_country`
        WHERE `country_a` = 'Russia'
       )
     )
   )
 )
 UNION (

 SELECT DISTINCT `country_b`
 FROM `relation_country`
 WHERE (
   `country_a` = 'USA'
   AND (
     `country_b`
     IN (

      SELECT `country_a`
      FROM `relation_country`
      WHERE `country_b` = 'Russia'
     )
    OR `country_b`
    IN (

     SELECT `country_b`
     FROM `relation_country`
     WHERE `country_a` = 'Russia'
    )
   )
  )
 )
```

Note using UNION for DISTINCT values.

Comment: If it works with you please upvote and mark as solved. And if you want any clarification go ahead and ask me.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. One more think Brother, I saw these result does not contained in a table, I mean how can I show in the page(website)Or how can I use your codes as PHP query directly into code editor.As I said I am really new, and these codes you gave me is totally new to me to use.

Comment: Brother, Thank you so much. I did transform to to php and it works well. Thank you again.

Comment: I accepted ur answer. But how to do upvote for you? I have no idea.

Comment: when someones answer was helpful even if it wasn't the full answer you upvote by using the arrow above the number on the left. It might require 15 reputation point.

Comment: I did(that day) in your Answer brother. look at this please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am giving for USA which is similar to Rassia

```
$USA1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM relation_country WHERE country_a= 'USA'");
$USA_numrows1 = mysql_num_rows($USA1);

if($USA_numrows1!=0){
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($USA1)){
        $country_b =$row1['country_b'];
        echo $country_b."<br/>";            
    }
}
```

$USA2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM relation_country WHERE country_b= 'USA'");
    $USA_numrows2 = mysql_num_rows($USA2);

```
if($USA_numrows2!=0){
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($USA2)){
        $country_a =$row2['country_a'];
        echo $country_a."<br/>";            
    }
}
```

$russia1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM relation_country WHERE country_a= 'russia'");
    $russia_numrows1 = mysql_num_rows($russia1);

```
if($russia_numrows1!=0){
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($russia1)){
        $country_b1 =$row3['country_b'];
        echo $country_b1."<br/>";           
    }
}
```

$russia2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM relation_country WHERE country_b= 'russia'");
    $russia_numrows2 = mysql_num_rows($russia2);

```
if($russia_numrows2!=0){
    while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($russia2)){
        $country_a1 =$row4['country_a'];
        echo $country_a1."<br/>";           
    }
}
```

Comment: 1st thing this handles only half of data.
You won't be handling if USA is in first column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, here is the sql result. Just to make the sql easier to follow creat the following view.

"create view xcountry as select country_a,country_b from relation_country union select country_b,country_a from relation_country;"

Then this select

"select country_b from xcountry where country_a = 'USA' and country_b in  (select country_b from xcountry where country_a = 'Rassia');"

the result is two rows; France and India.  Hope this helped.

Comment: These codes seems short enough and also new to me. Can you explain how to use(in sql/php)? please.

Comment: He joins the table twice: one correct and one reversed then uses normal select to one column only.

Comment: That's right. A view is just a manipulation on a table. It does not store data, It just look at it differently. By doing the union of the table with itself and the columns reversed, you get a view where all of the countries appear in the first column. The select after the "in" creates a set of all countries with a relation with Rassia. The select before the "in" get all of the countries with a relation with USA and are in the set.  Hope this helps.

Comment: If you think this was a simpler or better solution, please increase its value. I need the points :-)